# My UIButtons inside a scroll view aren't triggering their target function for some reason

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I've been coding with Xcode for about two years now and I've run into an issue regarding a series of UIButtons programmatically initialized in my custom scroll view. For whatever reason, when tapped, their target function `@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` isn't printing the statement "Button pressed!". I've never run into this issue before and I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction. I've included all the relevant code, although if this isn't enough I'd be happy to post the entire class's code.

```swift
{
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: -10, y: bottomView.layer.position.y - 340, width: view.frame.width + 20, height: 200)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    scrollView.layer.zPosition = 350
    scrollView.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
    scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let scrollContent = UIView()
    scrollContent.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 70
    let buttonSpacing: CGFloat = 15
    let numberOfButtonsPerRow = 6
    let numberOfRows = 2
    let padding: CGFloat = 20

    for row in 0..<numberOfRows {
        for col in 0..<numberOfButtonsPerRow {
            let button = UIButton()
          
            button.frame = CGRect(x: padding + CGFloat(col) * (buttonHeight + buttonSpacing),
                                  y: padding + CGFloat(row) * (buttonHeight + buttonSpacing),
                                  width: buttonHeight,
                                  height: buttonHeight)
        
            button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            button.backgroundColor = .black
            button.layer.zPosition = 500
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          
            button.layer.borderColor =  UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
            button.layer.borderWidth = 0.75
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
          
            button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)))
                  button.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
         
            let imageName = buttonImages[row * numberOfButtonsPerRow + col]
                  
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: imageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
            scrollContent.addSubview(button)
            scrollContent.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }

    let contentWidth = padding + CGFloat(numberOfButtonsPerRow) * (buttonHeight + buttonSpacing)
    let contentHeight = padding + CGFloat(numberOfRows) * (buttonHeight + buttonSpacing)
 
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
 
    scrollView.addSubview(scrollContent)
     
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
}

@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Button pressed!")
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding a tap gesture to a `UIButton`? You should be using `addTarget` (from `UIControl`).

Comment: I originally had it as you described but I was having the same issue so I tried adding a tap gesture to see if it would work any differently, but it still had the same result and I haven't modified it back yet. addTarget still didn't work either.

Comment: Use Xcode's "Debug View Hierarchy" and make sure the buttons have a proper size and make sure they are not being clipped by any of their superviews. And try setting the scroll view's contentSize *after* adding its subviews.

Comment: I just checked it out in the Debug View Hierarchy, and everything seems fine, still not sure why the buttons aren't reacting correctly

Comment: @joshuascode - I'm posting an answer below, but... Why aren't you using Auto-Layout? And, why are you positioning your scroll view relative to another view's **layer** position? And, why are you setting any view's `layer.zPosition`?

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are not "triggering their target function" because you are not tapping the buttons, even though you might *think* you are.

You cannot interact with UI elements that are **outside the bounds** of their superview (or that view's superview, and on up the chain).

Add this line to your code:

```
scrollContent.clipsToBounds = true
```

and run the app. Now, you won't even ***see*** any buttons.

You have to give `scrollContent` a width and height that encompasses the buttons.

You can get the buttons working with this line:

```
// give scrollContent a width and height that fits the buttons
scrollContent.frame.size = .init(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
```

A quick tip: during development, give all of your UI elements contrasting background colors so you can easily see the framing.

```
scrollContent.backgroundColor = .yellow
```